# press 'Enter' key to invoke a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page there is a button and a text box.

Originally I invoke a function by click the button. Now I also want to implement it by press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as well. But it is not working. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key doesn't reach myFunction.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#txt1").keyup(function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode == 13) {
             $("#btn1").click(myFunction);
         }
     });
         $('#btn1').click(myFunction);

     });
     function myFunction() {
         // do something, press enter key doesn't reach here.
         })
     }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost right: Just invoke the handler with `.click()`  or `.trigger('click')`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txt1").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which== 13) {
        $("#btn1").click(); // Just do a click.
     }
   });

     $('#btn1').click(myFunction); //Your handler is already registered here.

});
function myFunction() {
         // do something, press enter key doesn't reach here.

}
```

Also use **[event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)** instead of `event.keyCode` when inside jquery event handler as it normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`.

Comment: @Love Why do you have it inside a form? Your form's default action is being executed and page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$("#btn1").click(myFunction);
```

I reccommend to use:

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function () {
   myFunction();
});
```

And then:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
     $("#btn1").click(); //click the button
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujam6/)

Comment: No reason to change the first part. All you will do is turn it more verbose and lose the `this` reference inside `myFunction`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté For me is more readable. I like it more than using inline style.

Comment: Well yes, I like functional programming and the strong JS aspect of function objects being first-class citizens that you can pass references around. Okay that's mostly personal preference, though I just wanted to highlight that in case the `this` keyword or the original argument(s) (in this case the jQuery event object) is used inside `myFunction` it'd break in your modified approach. You should probably use `myFunction.apply(this, arguments)` but then it won't be "more readable" I'd guess. `=]`